# Detect if Multiple HDDs are RAID and it's RAID mode(windows)

Tags: c#, python, c++, powershell, cmd

In order to monitor system storage, I need to programmatically find :

1. if Multiple HDDs are used (done)
2. if Multiple HDDs are RAID (not done)
3. if they are RAID, what is the RAID mode (RAID0, RAID1, ...) (not even closed)

What I know/can:

- There are 2 types of RAID , **Hardware** and **Software**.
- If it's Software then it can be **RIAD0(striped)**, **RAID1(mirror)** and **RAID5**.
- I can find if it's software RAID by checking the volume name that is similar in every disk.

what I need to find :

- If it's software RAID how should I know RAID type? (in storage management I can see if the volume is striped or mirror but I cannot get this information programmatically)
- If it's hardware RAID how could I know that? how could I find it's RAID type

the programming language is not important, it could be CMD command, Powershell command or WMI or .....

Comment: You forgot the Java, c and PHP tags

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Unfortunately currently I'm limited to 5 tag

Comment: I have a motherboard with hardware raid (0,1,5,10). The operating system has no idea how the disks are configured.

Comment: @MohamadArmoon I was sarcastic due to your tag abuse. Your question as it is, is off-topic

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I understood what you were up to by that, but there should be a way to ask a question that can be solved somehow other than **my** knowledge of programming. so the better response to my so-called off-topic question would be a guide for me to express the question in a manner to achieve the best attention, not a sarcastic comment. by the way thanks for the attention

Comment: usually, there is a software (that comes with the controller) to communicate with the hardware (for configuration and checking)

Comment: @RichardCritten that's exactly what I achieved. the only software I found that can get this kind of data is intel rapid storage which does not have API to get information from(Programmatically)

Comment: Have you used `diskpart`? https://gist.github.com/schakko/4713248

Comment: Perhaps there is a chance to retrieve such information by `wmic`? I'm thinking of `wmic Volume` (or `wmic Partition` or `wmic LogicalDisk`)...

Comment: I used disk part through CMD but I couldn't find if the volume is **Striped** or **Mirror**.but it seems this script returns it, Currently, I don't have access to the server. I will inform you as soon as possible.